# How to detect a click on every single tab in tablayout?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I have a viewpager with undetermined pages, because the user can add pages too. Thats okay, but I have no idea how to make it possible, that my user could delete those pages. I have tried to implement a long click listener on every tab with the code below, but it is not working.

Then how to detect which one tab is clicked?

```
for (tabCounter = 0; tabCounter < DataOfPages.size(); tabCounter++) {
        tabLayout.getTabAt(tabCounter).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                dataSource.open();
                dataSource.deleteById(tabCounter);
                dataSource.close();

                setupViewPager(viewPager);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Implementation of `LongClick` listener to each `TAB`:**

```
LinearLayout tabStrip = (LinearLayout) tabLayout.getChildAt(0);

for (int i = 0; i < tabStrip.getChildCount(); i++) {

    // Set LongClick listener to each Tab        
    tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Tab clicked" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: I have used the same code and its work fine. Toast "Tab clicked" showing when i apply long press to any Tab

Comment: Then it is my fault, time to debug. Thanks for your answer :)